# Alternative to rspec double that does not fail test even if allow receive is not specified for a function

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking, double

Many times one outcome may have two different consequences that need to be tested with a test double. For example if a network connection is successful I'd like to log a message, and also pass the resource to another object that will store it internally. On the other hand it feels unclean to put these two in one test. For example this code fails:

```
describe SomeClass do
  let(:logger) { double('Logger') }
  let(:registry) { double('Registry') }
  let(:cut) { SomeClass.new }
  let(:player) { Player.new }

  describe "#connect" do
    context "connection is successful" do
      it "should log info" do
        logger.should_receive(:info).with('Player connected successfully')
        cut.connect player
      end

      it "should register player" do
        registry.should_receive(:register).with(player)
        cut.connect player
      end   
    end
  end
end
```

I could specify in each test that the function in the other one might get called, but that looks like unnecessary duplication. In that case I'd rather make this one test.

I also don't like that it's never explicit in the test that a method should NOT be called.

Does anyone know about an alternative that has an explicit 'should_not_receive' message instead of automatically rejecting calls that are not explicitly specified?

Answer (score 0):

RSpec supports `should_not_receive`, which is equivalent to `should_receive(...).exactly(0).times` as discussed in [this message](http://rubyforge.org/pipermail/rspec-users/2011-November/020743.html) from the original author of RSpec.